# How to run a script inside a private docker image

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are currently using CircleCI to run our automated tests and would like to migrate to Azure DevOps to run those tests on an Azure Pipeline. Our applications are fully dockerized and I am having trouble executing the tests in the container on Azure Pipeline.

My goal is simply to build the image, push it to our Docker Hub repo and then pull it to execute PHPUnit. The first part is OK, I managed to push the image.

Then I created a job to execute a simple script, and I would like for it to run inside the container. My pipeline conf file will follow. The step that fails currently is the container initialization of the second job. It fails with the error :

> /usr/bin/docker pull [redacted]:azure-master
> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for [redacted], repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

```yaml
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:  
  - job: Build_and_push
    displayName: Build and push image
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push image
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'Docker Hub'
        repository: '[redacted]'
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
        tags: 'azure-$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Login to docker repo
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'Docker Hub'
        command: 'login'
  - job: Install_composer_and_run_tests
    dependsOn: ['Build_and_push']
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    container: [redacted]:azure-$(Build.SourceBranchName)
    steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Login to docker repo
        inputs:
          containerRegistry: 'Docker Hub'
          command: 'login'
      - script: composer install -n --prefer-dist
      - script: php vendor/bin/phpunit tests/ --group me
```

I don't really understand how or where I should login because I use the `container` param in the job, not a task to pull the image. Plus I have not problem pushing the image even though I did not explicitly login at that step. Last thing is that I have created a container registry in Azure DevOps (`Docker Hub`), with my credentials and it works correctly.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me get it working! Sorry for the delay in my own response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints):

*Containers can be hosted on registries other than Docker Hub. To host an image on Azure Container Registry or another private container registry, add a service connection to the private registry. Then you can reference it in a container spec:*

```
container:
  image: xxx/xxx:tag
  endpoint: xxx
```

According to your error message, you may need to provide credentials for the `Initialize Containers` step. So we should use this format:

```
- job: Install_composer_and_run_tests
    dependsOn: ['Build_and_push']
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    container:
      image: [redacted]:azure-$(Build.SourceBranchName)
      endpoint: 'Docker Hub'
    steps:
      ...
```